# How to join tables without using join SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to grab information from multiple tables and output an end result: a list of all clients that have not placed a stock request yet. Displaying client number will be sufficient.

I am not allowed to use inner join or any type of join to achieve this.

So far this is what I have come up with.

```
SELECT c.clientNum
FROM client AS C, Stock_Request AS SR
WHERE C.clientNum NOT IN SR.ClientNum
```

This current attempt doesn't return the desired result.

Here is the information from the tables:

```
(client) 
    INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
        VALUES ('Mike');
    INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
        VALUES ('John');
    INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
        VALUES ('Sally');
    INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
        VALUES ('Margret');
    INSERT INTO Client (clientName)
        VALUES ('Max');

(stock request)
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2020-12-10',1);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2020-05-04',2);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2021-07-06',3);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2021-07-08',4);
INSERT INTO Stock_Request (requestDate, clientNum)
    VALUES ('2022-02-07',5);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you've *come up with so far* is using a JOIN, just with antiquated syntax that has been outdated for a couple of decades. Your restriction on not being able to use a JOIN in nonsense, because you can't perform the task without using one without at least using a subquery in the WHERE clause. Why can't you use a JOIN?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Do you get an error message? How are you executing the query?

Comment: Can you explain why you are not allowed to use join? Is this like a homework assignment or something?

Comment: FWIW, `NOT IN` should be followed by a parenthesis that contains either a list of values or a subquery. See the [documentation for the IN() predicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it through this code:

```
SELECT clientNum FROM `client`
WHERE clientNum 
NOT IN (SELECT clientNum FROM stock_request GROUP BY clientNum);
```

You don't need to indicate the stock_request table on your main `SELECT`, you just need to use the stock_request table to fetch all the `clientNum` in a subquery by using `IN`, I think your using `IN` the wrong way.

Check more about **[MySQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_in.asp)**.